# Google API batch requests handling of next page tokens

Tags: python, google-api-python-client, google-classroom

Having an issue with handling nextpagetoken and how to add these to a batch requests.

Any ideas appreciated. current code goes through the page tokens one by one if there is a page token but is slowing it down drastically!

```
def iftoken(nextPageToken, requestId):
    while True:
        studentSubmissions = service_two.courses().courseWork().studentSubmissions().list(pageToken=nextPageToken,
                                                                                          courseId=requestId,
                                                                                          courseWorkId='-').execute()
        assignments.extend(studentSubmissions.get('studentSubmissions', []))
        nextPageToken = studentSubmissions.get('nextPageToken', None)
        if not nextPageToken:
            break
def makeRequestWithExponentialBackoff(analytics):
    for n in range(0, 5):
        try:
            response = service_two.courses().courseWork().studentSubmissions().list(pageToken=None, courseId=v['id'],
                                                                                    courseWorkId='-', pageSize=100000)
            print(response.get("studentSubmissions", []))
            return assignments.extend(response.get("nextPageToken", []))

        except:
            time.sleep((2 ** n) + random.random())
            continue
    print("There has been an error, the request never succeeded.")


def callback(request_id, response, exception):
    if exception is not None:
        print('Error getting assignments "{0}" for course: "{1}"'.format(request_id, exception))
        makeRequestWithExponentialBackoff(request_id)
    else:
        assignments.extend(response.get("studentSubmissions", []))
        nextPageToken = response.get("nextPageToken", None)
        if nextPageToken:
            iftoken(nextPageToken, request_id)
        else:
            pass


for k, v in filtered.iterrows():
    if count % 1000 == 0:
        submit = batch.execute(http=http)
        batch_count += 1
        print(batch_count)
        time.sleep(30)
        batch_array.append({'batchSent {}'.format(v['id'])})
        batch = None
        batch = service_two.new_batch_http_request(callback=callback)
        response = service_two.courses().courseWork().studentSubmissions().list(pageToken=None, courseId=v['id'],
                                                                                courseWorkId='-', pageSize=100000)
        batch.add(response, request_id=v['id'])
        array.append({'email': v['primaryEmail'], 'count': count, 'classid': v['id']})
        count = 1
    elif count % 1000 != 0 and batch == None:
        batch = service_two.new_batch_http_request(callback=callback)
        response = service_two.courses().courseWork().studentSubmissions().list(pageToken=None, courseId=v['id'],
                                                                                courseWorkId='-', pageSize=100000)
        batch.add(response, request_id=v['id'])
        array.append({'email': v['primaryEmail'], 'count': count, 'classid': v['id']})
        count += 1
    else:
        response = service_two.courses().courseWork().studentSubmissions().list(pageToken=None, courseId=v['id'],
                                                                                courseWorkId='-', pageSize=100000)
        batch.add(response, request_id=v['id'])
        array.append({'email': v['primaryEmail'], 'count': count, 'classid': v['id']})
        count += 1
```

where filtered is a dataframe of classroom Ids. However got an issue with the nextpagetokens and how to add these to the dataframe?

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail what this code is doing? What do you mean by adding the nextPageTokens to the DataFrame? Also, how did you decide to make batch requests for this?